# Increment calendar with day

Tags: java, date, time, calendar

I have a strange problem when i increment days in Calendar. I want to loop over every day of a year. This is my code

```
Date d = null;
SimpleDateFormat textFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String paramDateAsString = "10-1-2012";
d = textFormat.parse(paramDateAsString);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
cal.setTime(d);

for(int i = 0; i < 365; i++) {
   cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
   System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-"+cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1+"-         "+cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+" 00:00:00'");
}
```

I get this output:

> ...
>   2012-01-29 00:00:00'
>   2012-01-30 00:00:00'
>   2012-01-31 00:00:00'
>   2012-11-1 00:00:00'
>   2012-11-2 00:00:00'
>   ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
"-"+cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1
```

That's actually performing *string* concatenation - it's effectively

```
("-" + cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)) + 1
```

So when `cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)` returns 1, that's effectively:

```
("-" + 1) + 1 // which is...
"-1" + 1 // which is...
"-11"
```

You *could* just bracket the addition:

```
"-" + (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)
```

... but it would be better to use `SimpleDateFormat` to perform the formatting instead of doing it manually.